# How to check match data in vba excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 cols with data in sheet. I need to compare if it match, I'll push them into the third col.

This's my code:

```
Sub Match()

Dim c1 As Range
Dim c2 As Range
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserACL+User02")

Dim CellCounter As Integer
Dim TempFound As Boolean
CellCounter = 2

For Each c1 In sh.Range("B2:B200")
TempFound = False
    For Each c2 In sh.Range("C2:C200")
        If c1.Value = c2.Value Then
            sh.Range(CellCounter, 4).Value = c1.Value
            CellCounter = CellCounter + 1
            TempFound = True
        Else
            TempFound = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next c2
Next c1
```

End Sub

It can run but nothing happen to the third col. pls help

Answer (score 0):

one fast, easy way to mach 2 column can be

```
 
Sub Match()
    Dim arrcell As Variant, i As Variant
    arrcell = Range("B2:C200")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrcell)
        If arrcell(i, 1) = arrcell(i, 2) Then Cells(i + 1, 4) = arrcell(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: I just modify your code.
here:

Sub Match()
    Dim arrcell As Variant, i As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("UserACL+User02")
    arrcell = sh.Range("B2:C200")
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrcell)
        If arrcell(i, 1) = arrcell(i, 2) Then Cells(i + 1, 4) = arrcell(i, 1)
    Next i
End Sub

but nothing happen just like my old code

Comment: I have now tried (now) the code with your edits (sh name), it works perfectly.
Do you have do one debug? where you find error